# Why is axistools-maven-plugin trying to access this relative schema location?

Tags: java, maven-2, axis, wsdl2java

We're doing a web service project with Axis 1.x and I'm having problems getting the Maven build to work.

I do a

```
 mvn clean generate-sources
```

which triggers axistools-maven-plugin's `wsdl2java` goal. It eventually aborts with

```
[INFO] [axistools:wsdl2java {execution: generate-project}]
[INFO] about to add compile source root
[INFO] Processing wsdl: C:\Project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\wsdl\project.wsdl
Jan 24, 2011 11:24:58 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error generating Java code from WSDL.

Embedded error: Error running Axis
C:\Project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\project.xsd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

This is correct. That file doesn't exist. (And -e yields no additional useful information -- it's a LifecycleExecutionException, caused by a MojoExecutionException, caused by an AxisPluginException, caused by a FileNotFoundException.)

The point is, it shouldn't search for `WEB-INF\project.xsd`, it should access `WEB-INF\wsdl\project.xsd`.

Here's what the WSDL says:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://domain/project/">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://domain/schema/" schemaLocation="project.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

This seems to work fine for all my coworkers. We're all using Maven 2.2.1 and axistools-maven-plugin is pinned to 1.4 with the following configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-project</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/</sourceDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
          <serverSide>true</serverSide>
          <testCases>false</testCases>
          <wrapArrays>false</wrapArrays>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I already completely cleared my local Maven repository, hoping that it was a rogue dependency, but that didn't change anything. Any idea what could be causing this just for me, but not for my coworkers?

---

EDIT 1: I tried changing the schemaLocation to `wsdl/project.xsd` (just for testing purposes, I won't be able to make any permanent modifications to the WSDL) and got this amusing result:

```
Embedded error: Error running Axis
WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema):
    faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve
    schema referenced at 'wsdl\project.xsd', relative to
    'file:/C:/Project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/project.wsdl'.:
    This file was not found:
    file:/C:/Project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/wsdl/project.xsd
```

If you are, like me, now thinking that maybe `./project.xsd` might work... nope, sorry, that makes it search directly for `WEB-INF/project.xsd` again.

---

EDIT 2: Okay, now axistools is just teasing me...

`../project.xsd`
  --> `src/main/webapp/project.xsd` (wrong)

`../wsdl/project.xsd`
  --> `src/main/webapp/wsdl/project.xsd` (wrong)

`../WEB-INF/wsdl/project.xsd`
  --> `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/WEB-INF/wsdl/project.xsd` (wrong)

As a reminder, the correct path would be `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/project.xsd`.

Comment: Did you try mvn clean generate-sources?

Comment: @Raghuram: Yes, that's what I'm actually doing. I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: Did you redact the project directory name for SO? I think this issue occurs if you have spaces in the path..Common on Win XP

Comment: @Martin The project name is definitely redacted. I can't remember whether there were any spaces in the original path, but I'm fairly sure that I explicitly tried it on a simplified (read: close to root, no spaces) directory. I also think spaces in the path would lead to different behavior and other error messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the useEmitter tag like:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <useEmitter>true</useEmitter>
```

...

Comment: Hard to tell what the implications of using this flag are. Documentation is pretty sparse -- there's just [this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/wsdl2java-mojo.html#useEmitter), which doesn't mention what the emitter does differently to the command line wsdl2java tool. It definitely seems to fix the original issue, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by ensuring that the path of the project location does not contain spaces. Therefore, the default location on Win XP will not work ("Documents and Settings")

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when `<useEmitter>` is enabled `<subPackageByFileName>` feature does not work anymore.

So I had to split generation into two "executions"

- first all WSDLs without XSD and with `<subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>`
- and then the one with XSD include (luckily I have just one) with `<useEmitter>true</useEmitter>` (and the file name explicitly added to `<packageSpace>`)

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue while building with maven as mentioned and I was able to resolve this issue by ensuring that the path of the project location does not contain spaces.