# axis wsdl2java fails reading schema with special characters

Tags: java, wsdl2java, axis

I'm trying to generate a Java Client with the axis using `wsdl2java` (wrapped by the maven axistools).

I downloaded the wsdl and the corresponding schema.

The wsdl has the following schema definitions:

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema 
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/CM_IntegrationService/"
  xmlns:pref="http://example.com/CM_IntegrationService" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com//CM_IntegrationService"
      schemaLocation="CM_IntegrationService?xsd=ServiceModel_CM_IntegrationService.xsd"/>
```

In short:

> schemaLocation="CM_IntegrationService?xsd=ServiceModel_CM_IntegrationService.xsd"

The error shows as:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:wsdl2java
>   (default) on project wsclient-cm: Error generating Java code from WSDL. error running 
>   file:/C:/workspace/ws/wsclient-reactor/wsclient-wsdl/src/main/wsdl/CM_IntegrationService.wsdl:
>
> WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR:
>   An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced
>   at 'CM_IntegrationService?xsd=ServiceModel_CM_IntegrationService.xsd', relative to 
>   'file:/C:/workspace/ws/wsclient-reactor/shop-wsclient-wsdl/src/main/wsdl/CM_IntegrationService.wsdl'.:
>
> This file was not found: 
>   file:/C:/workspace/ws/wsclient-reactor/wsclient-wsdl/src/main/wsdl/CM_IntegrationService?xsd=ServiceModel_CM_IntegrationService.xsd -> [Help 1]

In short file not found for:

> /C:/workspace/ws/wsclient-reactor/wsclient-wsdl/src/main/wsdl/CM_IntegrationService?xsd=ServiceModel_CM_IntegrationService.xsd

Is there a way to specify which schema to use? I saved the schema as `ServiceModel_CM_IntegrationService.xsd`. However its searching for the full path including `=` and `?` which I cannot emulate on the file system.

I don't want to modify the wsdl as suggested in: [WSDL to Java -client creation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344881/wsdl-to-java-client-creation-error)

[Why is axistools-maven-plugin trying to access this relative schema location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781028/why-is-axistools-maven-plugin-trying-to-access-this-relative-schema-location) looks similar however using the `useEmitter=true` option didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible without modifying the WSDL. Doing this without modifying the WSDL (BTW, why don't you want to do that?) would require support for XML catalogs, as described in [AXIS-1984](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-1984).

Comment: The idea is to directly download the files and start the service generation with maven. Manual interaction should be kept to a minimum so that its not an error source. Steps that can be avoided don't produce errors. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Then why don't you feed the HTTP URL directly to wsdl2java?

Comment: Thought about that as well. However the server with the webservice isn't up all the time and its not always carrying the newest version.